# Autofac begin lifetimescope per activated instance

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

Given following code:

```
interface IMain {}
interface ISub {}
interface IDep {}

class Dep : IDep
{
    public Dep(ISub sub) { ... }
}

class Main : IMain
{
     public Main() {}

     public IEnumerable<IDep> Dependencies {get;set}
}
```

How can i configure the container to have one single instance of ISub per IMain instance. So if I resolve an IMain instance from the container, a 'single instance' of ISub is created for that IMain object.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by registering ISub as InstancePerLifetimeScope and controlling lifetimescope of IMain instace manually. Sample code:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Main>().As<IMain>().InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<Dep>().As<IDep>().InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<Sub>().As<ISub>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
var container = builder.Build();

using (var lifetimeScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var main = lifetimeScope.Resolve<IMain>();
}
```